# Can you use insight on someone with ring of mind shielding?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, skills

I know that the description of this item is

> While wearing this ring, you are immune to magic that allows other creatures to read your thought, determine whether you are lying, know your alignment, or know your creature type.

But does this include insight checks? And if so, would the DC be the wearer's wisdom spell DC?

Answer (score 17):

### Insight checks are non-magical.

The description only states that you're immune to **magic** that does those things. However, an insight check is not magical (PHB 178):

> Your Wisdom (Insight) check decides whether you can determine the true intentions of a creature ... Doing so involves gleaning clues from body language, speech habits, and changes in mannerisms.

Thus, the ring does not protect you from ordinary, non-magical insight checks.

As for DCs, there aren't any specific rules as to what the DC should be. Given that the interaction is wholly nonmagical, I usually use a contested deception vs. insight check when a scenario like this arises.

Comment: What about the DC? How do I decide whether it succeeds or not?

Comment: There are rules for DC, just not specifically for insight. You pick a range of diffficulty for an NPC as for any other challenge, or roll deception, or can make a passive deception DC based on the NPC skill total.